# Delete select instances from an emitter

Tags: particles

I have an emitter particle system I animated with physics, and I need to delete particles that collide. Is there a way to realize instance WITH the animation as position keys, or delete specific particles like with the hair system?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but I believe the 'Kill Particles' system in the Collision Object settings might help (assuming that your particles are colliding with a Collision Object):

[image]

Comment: no, I need to delete particles overlapping with other particles from the same emitter